# Run function after post is updated

Tags: posts, functions, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

I would like to run a function after a post is saved. That function takes a .txt file thats uploaded with `Advanced Custom Field` file field, makes it into an array to then a json data. I want the json data to be saved into the database.

I've read on `update_post_meta()` and I'm assuming that that's what might be the best option.

I'm confused on where I would place this function. Is it in my theme's `function.php` file? Is this technically a plugin? And if so, where would it go?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How familiar are you with hooks and filters? You're correct in that update_post_meta is the correct function to do the work, the problem is not where in your theme you should place it, it's a problem of ***when*** not where

Comment: @TomJNowell not really familiar with hooks and filters. So in my case when would you say?